# How can I detect the Flowdirection RightToLeft or LeftToRight automatically in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, direction

Is there a way to detect the FlowDirection in TextBox automatically based on the Unicode Characters used?

If you have an Arabic text in Excel it is automatically aligned to the right side of the cell. I would like the same logic in my WPF application. Has anyone experience with this and can tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base your solution in...
http://windows-tech.info/13/5fa183aedccd93df.php

the relevant code is

```
public bool IsArabic(string strCompare)
{
  char[] chars = strCompare.ToCharArray();
  foreach (char ch in chars)
    if (ch >= '\u0627' && ch <= '\u0649') return true;
  return false;
}
```

Also check the Arabic section of the Unicode standard...
http://www.unicode.org/charts/