# How to split culture specific strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, cultureinfo

I need to split the following string into string[].

```
string tempstring = "د.ع.‏123,456.00";// culture "ku-Arab-IQ"
string[] temp = tempstring.Split(".".ToCharArray());
```

But I am getting the following answer:

```
{string[4]}
    [0]: "د"
    [1]: "ع"
    [2]: "‏123,456"
    [3]: "00"
```

I expect the answer to be like:

```
{string[4]}

[0]: "‏123,456"
[1]: "00"
[2]: "د"
[3]: "ع"
```

> **Edit:**
>   But the above-mentioned splitting works fine for the string **"123,456.00 د.ع.‏"** (Culture - "ar-IQ")
>   Result:

```
 {string[4]}
        [0]: "123,456"
        [1]: "00 د"
        [2]: "ع"
        [3]: "‏"
```

I think both of the strings are RTL text, but splitting results differ in both cases. Could you please help me, how to split this string properly. or whether this is the correct splitting.

Comment: I don't think you expectation is expected... (Almost mandatory https://xkcd.com/1137/). Some good reasoning why you think you should be getting different result with RTL string would be welcome improvement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing through Arabic / RTL text from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630566/parsing-through-arabic-rtl-text-from-left-to-right)

Comment: @GaurangDave: I will check the shared question and close this if it is working for my case.

Comment: `123,456.00 د.ع.‏` IS NOT EQUAL TO `د.ع.‏123,456.00`. It has space symbol between `00` and `.`, so it splits in differ way. Now, you have 2 different words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This string contains right to left substrings, so, you get correct result.

`د` is the first substring, because it's right to left,

`ع` is the second by the same reason

`‏123,456` is usual left to right string, so it's third

`00` is forth

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have edited the question slightly.

Comment: @Venkat what do you want to get after splitting?

Comment: I have added two example strings in the questions, I think both are RTL. One string results like you explained in the above answer, the second one results like the one I expected in the question. So Please share whether the splitting is proper or anything I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: @Venkat you will never get result as you expect for RTL strings. So, what is your question? `string.Split` is working well