# How do I find a Unicode character's bidirectional character type in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, internationalization, bidi

Is there any way I can find a Unicode character's bidirectional character type in C#?

I want to look through the characters in a string and decide if they are all strong LTR, strong RTL, a mixture of strong LTR and neutral, etc.

Comment: Maby this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330951/how-to-detect-whether-a-character-belongs-to-a-right-to-left-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetBidiCategory(ch)` is your friend.

The problem is that the function is internal. [This MichKap (RIP) blog post](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/06/1421178.aspx) shows you how to call it using reflection.

Comment: You can get exactly the same information with [char structure's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) static methods. The problem is, none of them will give you the directionality.

Comment: OK, it seems that I am a bit wrong as the char methods will give you Unicode category and not BiDi category. Somehow they don't think this information is useful.

Comment: I also thought I would find it in `Char` as well ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Serge. That blog post is spot on.

Comment: This doesn't work on Android. For some reason it can't find the GetBidiCategory function when compiled in Release, in Debug it finds it.