# c# split and reverse sentence with two languages

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I have a sentence like this (in Hebrew,RTL):

**ואמר was here  אוראל**

Now, when I insert this into array I got:

1. array[0] = אוראל
2. array[1] = was
3. array[2] = here
4. array[3] = :ואמר

Now, because Hebrew is a RTL language I need to reverse the english letters and I need to switch the positions.
Notice that I need to take care of any sentence (which means I can have more than two english words).

How do I get the result to be like the following?

**ואמר ereh saw   אוראל**

I thought maybe to build any time a new string with just the english words,Reverse it and build the original string again, or maybe use in ref strings...

---

thanks for your helping but i still got a problem!
i had splited the sentence as you said,i reversed the array and
i got this:

**לארוא ereh saw רמאו**

after the step 2 the postions of the hebrew words are worng!
in step 3 i reversed the hebrew words again and i got:

**אוראל ereh saw ואמר**

and i need to switch their position(one in one, as i said i can
have a sentence with a lot of words..)
so, i didn't understand how i "put the array string back together"(step 5)

Comment: Is it homework of a kind - mark with "homework" tag... It is also unclear what you have problem with - you listed several approaches but no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paolo did the hard work of figuring out the algorithm:

> 1. Split a sentence into an array of strings
> 2. Reverse the Array
> 3. If a word is not in Hebrew reverse it
> 4. Join the strings

Here is a more elegant version using LINQ:

```
var result = Sentence
   .Split(' ')
   .Reverse()
   .Select(w => IsHebrew(w) ? w : new String(w.Reverse().ToArray())
   .Join(" ")
```

Comment: Fixed "x" was supposed to be "w"

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you split the problem into pieces, it would look like this. You need to:

1. [Split a sentence into an array of strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [reverse the Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx#Y0)
3. [Detect if a word is in Hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330951/how-to-detect-whether-a-character-belongs-to-a-right-to-left-language)
4. if it is not in Hebrew you need to [Reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622714/497364) the string
5. now you just need to [put the array of strings back together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings) in one string and you're done!

EDIT:
I misunderstood your problem. You could do something like this:

```
    public static string ProcessEnglishHebrewSentence(string sentence)
    {
        var ret = new List<string>();
        string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

        var curHebrewList = new List<string>();
        var curEnglishList = new List<string>();
        bool curLangIsHebrew=false;

        foreach(var w in words)
        {
            if(IsHebrew(w) && curLangIsHebrew) // we have a word in Hebrew and the last word was in Hebrew too
            {
                curHebrewList.Add(w);
            }
            else if(IsHebrew(w) && !curLangIsHebrew) // we have a word in Hebrew and the last word was in English
            {
                if(curEnglishList.Any())            {
                    curEnglishList.Reverse();
                    ret.AddRange(curEnglishList);
                } // reverse current list of English words and add to List
                curEnglishList = new List<string>(); // create a new empty list for the next series of English words
                curHebrewList.Add(w);
                curLangIsHebrew=true; // set current language to Hebrew
            }
            else if(!IsHebrew(w) && !curLangIsHebrew) // we have a word in English and the last word was in English
            {
                curEnglishList.Add(new String(w.Reverse().ToArray())); // reverse and add it to the current series of English words
            }
            else if(!IsHebrew(w) && curLangIsHebrew) // we have a word in English and the last word was in Hebrew
            {
                if(curHebrewList.Any()) ret.AddRange(curHebrewList); // add current list of Hebrew words to List of Lists
                curHebrewList = new List<string>(); // create a new empty list for the next series of Hebrew words
                curEnglishList.Add(new string(w.Reverse().ToArray()));
                curLangIsHebrew=false; // set current language to English
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("there should be no other case...");
            }
        }
        if(curHebrewList.Any()) ret.AddRange(curHebrewList);
        if(curEnglishList.Any())
        {
            curEnglishList.Reverse();
            ret.AddRange(curEnglishList);
        }

        return ret.Aggregate((a,b) => a + " " + b);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your helping but i still got a problem!
i had splited the sentence as you said,i reversed the array and
i got this:
לארוא ereh saw רמאו
after the step 2 the postions of the hebrew words are worng!
in step 3 i reversed the hebrew words again and i got:
אוראל ereh saw ואמר
and i need to switch their position(one in one,as i said i can
have a sentence with a lot of words..)
so,i didnt understand how i "put the array string back together"(step 5)
help!

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question: I thought you needed to reverse the whole sentence and make only the english words right-to-left. Now I understand the words in hebrew should maintain their place and the words in english should be reversed. What I don't understand is how this would work in the general case. For instance, say h1, h2 and h3 are words in hebrew and e1, e2, e3 are words in english: how would you process a sentence like h1, e1, e2, h2, h3, e3? Should it become h1, e2(backwards), e1(backwards), h2, h3, e3(backwards)? Or h1, e3(backwards), e2(backwards), h2, h3, e1(backwards)?

Comment: yes it's will be:
h1, e1, e2, h2, h3, e3 =

h1, e2(backwards), e1(backwards), h2, h3, e3(backwards)