# LTR and RTL String Split Irrespective of the Language Directionality

Tags: c#, string, right-to-left

Long story short, I have a text in the following manner:

`const string example1 = "good בוקר טוב morning";`

I am trying to split the above text into 4 words (in my case tokens) for processing. No matter what approach I take I still get the 2 Hebrew words in the wrong order. By order I mean the *display* order and not the *logical* order.

When using `String.Split` for **example1**

**Returned**

- good
- בוקר
- טוב
- morning

*In the above you may notice the 2 Hebrew words are now in the wrong (display) position*.

**Expected**

- good
- טוב
- בוקר
- morning

I have tried using *Regex.Split*, forcing invariant cultures and even appending Unicode characters for splitting in LTR order of display.

Though I am not keen on solving this via *Regex* I am looking for a generic approach to such problem that would stay intact in other RTL languages say Arabic.

Before making this post I have checked the following in case it gets marked as duplicate by others.

[Parsing through Arabic / RTL text from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630566/parsing-through-arabic-rtl-text-from-left-to-right)
 - *Presumes that the developer knows where the RTL word is located. I am not using a semi-colon as a word separator. It can be any culture specific character. Also, adding an invisible marker would result in future string equality comparison failure.*

[c# split and revers sentence with two languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622610/c-sharp-split-and-revers-sentence-with-two-languages)
 - *The character order is modified. I wish to keep them intact.*

Any advice or suggestion that puts me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Is your example there the order you get them in? Or the order you want them to be in?

Comment: @MattBurland Sorry I didn't add that in there. It's the order I am getting it in. I shall update the post to avoid further confusions.

Comment: @MattBurland Marking duplicate in seconds proves for itself you didn't actually care to read the post. It is not a duplicate of what you've  suggested. In that post the resolution provided presumes that the developer knows where the RTL words are located and has to explicitly add a Left-to-Right marker (\U+200E) for each RTL word.