# In which order RTL language (Hebrew, Arabic, etc) strings are stored in memory?

Tags: c#, string, memory, right-to-left

And how does the OS know whether to apply bidi algorithms on the string for displaying purposes?

I know that Hebrew might come in an ISO-Logical form, but how does the OS know how to point that a specific string contains Hebrew (or any other RTL language)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to detect whether a character belongs to a Right To Left language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330951/how-to-detect-whether-a-character-belongs-to-a-right-to-left-language) - it seems they are stored left-to-right, and it's the character codes that dictate whether it's a RTL language.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this nowadays, as recommended by the Unicode standard, is to store text in logical order (good explanation [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter04a#f618274b)), which means the order in which it is read.

The OS knows that a specific string contains Hebrew by looking at the character codes. It applies the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) to determine the correct display order. Typically an OS will do a quick scan of the string first to see if there are any right-to-left characters or control codes constraining the order. If not, the string doesn't need reordering.