# How not to make dir='rtl' send special characters like . / + to the left side?

Tags: html, css

When I am trying to add text to the div (div has dir = RTL), it moves the content to the right side. However, it keeps the special characters like . / + to the left side, if they are the last character for the sentence.

Example:

> `<dir dir="RTL">Hello There!</dir>`

Out put will be:
!Hello There

Could any one help with this?

Comment: Why are you using `dir='rtl'` for content that is not in a right-to-left language? If you just want to align text to the right, use `text-align: right` in CSS (or `align=right` in HTML for the elements that allow it).

Comment: I also want this because I want text aligned on the left, but when it overflows its box, I want the ellipsis (using `text-overflow: ellipsis`) to appear on the left, not the right as usual. `dir='rtl'` works, except for the weird symbol displacement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `<bdi>` (bi-directional text) tag to wrap your text, [**see this article**](http://davidwalsh.name/rtl-punctuation)

```
<div dir="RTL">
   <bdi>
      Hello There!
   </bdi>
</div>
```

[**More on `bdi` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi)

Unfortunately this is only supported in Chrome and FireFox.

As [Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela) mentions, this will effectively accomplish the same as right-aligning your text, in which case you should be doing that.

### [See here for a list of examples](http://jsfiddle.net/3Na76/)

Comment: `<bdi>` is just bidi isolate. The `<bdo>`, bidi override, has much better support and works if you use `<bdo dir=ltr>...</bdo>`. But it sounds so... odd to ask for RTL and yet want LTR, which is what the question seems to be asking.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - that's a better answer +1

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The reason im asking for RTL and want LTR is that I want some thing like google's "Scientific Claculator" display.. it goes from right to left ....I tried many methods but they are not working for me. So I went with this route...

Comment: @SW4 If I add this bdo or bdi, it is just going LTR again as you said. But I want it to be RTL and have punctuation to the right too... Is there any way?

Comment: @narsi, you should edit the question to explain what you are really doing. Show a mini-example with just a few items. You probably need to set RTL direction for a list element and LTR direction for elements inside it, or something like that.

Comment: @narsi adding &lrm; at the end worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551367/1555348