# Can I put Ellipsis on the Left and Periods on the Right?

Tags: css

Moving the Ellipsis (...) to the left is done easily with:

```
.overflow-box{
    direction: rtl;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But what if there's punctuation at the end, like a period (.) or question mark?  It's also displayed on the left.  I'd still like to see the period on the right.  Is there an easy way around this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/JoelMac/Lx4L15o3/5/

Comment: [`<span dir="ltr">Where is the question mark?</span>`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx4L15o3/7/)

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister, that's exactly what I needed.  If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the content of the div in a span with `dir="ltr"`, forcing the content to be rendered in the standard order while still cutting off to the left as desired.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span dir="ltr">This is a sentence that is too long to fit in the space provided.
  The ellipsis is where I want it.</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span dir="ltr">Where is the question mark?</span>
</div>
```

However, this is not the only possible solution. As @reiallenramos's answer shows, you can also insert `&lrm;` at the end of the content; that will work too.
An added benefit of the latter approach is that you won't need to change the markup; you can do it wholly in CSS, as follows:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::after {
  content:'\200E';
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is a sentence that is too long to fit in the space provided.
  The ellipsis is where I want it.
</div>

<div>
  Where is the question mark?
</div>
```

This would then be my preferred method, but you can choose whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: append `&lrm;` to the end of your text like this

```
<div>
Where is the question mark?&lrm;
</div>
```

Looks like a duplicate of [Why is a trailing punctuation mark rendered at the start with direction:rtl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798667/why-is-a-trailing-punctuation-mark-rendered-at-the-start-with-directionrtl)

Punctuations really do behave this way according to [this](http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html).