# use direction="rtl" in pre with html tags

Tags: html

I try to figure out why in Pre tag with direction="dir" attributes with quotes in html tags looks wrong and how it can be fixed.

Print inside `pre` element html tags with attributes and quotes:

```
<html meta="test">
```

looks like this:

```
<"html meta="test>
```

css attribute `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;` not fits for me, i need to safe html tags structure.

live example:
https://codepen.io/justillusion/pen/GRGoRNv

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `&lrm` to your punctuations seems to have fixed the problem.

Your snippet would look something like this;

```
   <pre>
        &lt;html meta= test"&lrm;&gt;
        Hello, World!
        &lt;/html&gt;
    </pre>
```

For more explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551367/11226302

There may be other solutions/workarounds as well, but this is what I found to be most practical and useful in cases such as yours!